# Sharp bevel effect in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]I am trying to create a bevel effect similar to the attached image. I have set the depth to 30%, size to 1px and soften to 0px, but the final effect has bevels which are not as crisp as those on the attached image - the bevels look very slightly blurred. Any advice on the necessary settings to recreate the bevels seen in this image please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **size to 0px** on the Bevel to get it very crisp. But 1px schould do exactly what you see in the picture you posted. What I also see in your image is an inner glow (black) which might add to the desired effect you are looking for.

This is depth 100% and size 1px plus an inner glow of 5px and 25%:

[image]

Comment: Setting the size to 0 helped a lot - thank You! I tried your second suggestion b as well, but when I add the drop shadow and set its angle to -90, it also adjusts the angle of the inner shadow?

Comment: Deselect the box that says "Use Global Light" in the drop shadow preferences

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your mode to "Chisel Hard". If that doesn't work, try working with the bevel profile (next selection down on the tree).

Comment: Setting the mode to Chisel had no visible effect unfortunately